# Scene builder import to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx

Ive recently discovered that you are able to use JavaFx Scene builder to build your GUI

ive become very tired of the build in gui builder that Eclipse offers

So i wanted to try out Scene builder but i am not sure how i import it into my Eclipse project and actually use it with my program?

Ive been looking all over to find a step by step guide but so far ive had no luck finding one for eclipse (for netbeans there are loads but so far ive found none for eclipse)

I hope some of you are able to help me with this or guide me through the steps i need to take

Best Regards
Marc Rasmussen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some background info:

1. SceneBuilder is for building [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) apps.
2. [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) is the unofficial JavaFX tooling for Eclipse.
3. Currently SceneBuilder runs as a standalone application.
4. SceneBuilder outputs [fxml](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) files.
5. SceneBuilder can optionally be embedded in NetBeans.
6. Future builds of e(fx)clipse may also offer to embed SceneBuilder in Eclipse.
7. e(fx)clipse will compile and build javafx applications - including ones which input fxml which has been output by SceneBuilder.
8. The key class which ties together JavaFX applications and fxml generated by SceneBuilder is the [FXMLLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html).

Tutorial track for building applications with SceneBuilder and e(fx)clipse:

1. Install [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (download under 'Additional resources') and [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/install.html) seperately as well as [jdk7u6+](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
2. Using e(fx)clipse, try the compiling and running the [basic JavaFX sample apps](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm), especially the fxml related sample.
3. Run through the [Getting Started with SceneBuilder Sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm), but use e(fx)clipse to compile and run the code rather than NetBeans.
4. Try out the [Mastering FXML tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm) - but create the FXML in SceneBuilder and build your project using e(fx)clipse.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!

i will have a look at those guys, but as far as i can see it should be easy enough to implement with your code or would you consider it to be too much hassel?

Comment: When i try to install e(fx)clipse it says:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: e4 pde 0.1.0.201207201416 (at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.pde4.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201207201416)
  Missing requirement: E4 PDE 0.1.0.201207201416 (at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.pde.e4 0.1.0.201207201416) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench 0.10.1' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: e4 pde 0.1.0.201207201416 (at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.pde4.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201207201416)

Comment: I advise posting your e(fx)clipse installation issue to the [e(fx)clipse forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/efxclipse).

Comment: Now JavaFx is officially with java 8.Follow the instructions described in this url http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/work-with-java-ides/index.html